# Difference between InputMethodManager SHOW_FORCED and SHOW_IMPLICIT in Android

Tags: android, android-input-method

I would like to know the behavioral difference of the constants `SHOW_FORCED` and`SHOW_IMPLICIT`. I tried both and couldn't see any difference in the first look.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`SHOW_FORCED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#SHOW_FORCED) and [`SHOW_IMPLICIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#SHOW_IMPLICIT) work in tandem with the hiding methods [`HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY) and [`HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS).

Using `SHOW_FORCED` indicates that the user has explicitly requested that the keyboard be shown (such as by pressing an "open keyboard" button), and thus the system should force it to open. In this case, any existing request to hide the keyboard using the above flags will be ignored (thus the keyboard is "forced" open).

Using `SHOW_IMPLICIT` means that your app thinks the user wants the keyboard open, but hasn't explicitly requested it. In this case, requests to hide the keyboard with `HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` or `HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` will still be respected.